# Citrix Netscaler TOTP Authenticator secret is a plain text or is it encoded or encrypted?

Tags: citrix, totp, app-secret

I have no experience in Citrix space, I have a client who wants to migrate Citrix TOTP to Azure AD B2C.
The Citrix TOTP is synced with On Prem Ad to AAD and the TOTP secret is received as a OIDC claim to B2C.
The issue is after migrating the secret to Azure AD b2c the OTP code is not validating by Azure AD B2C,always throws wrong code entered. Azure AD B2C accept only plain secret,i am wondering if any one know what encoding or encryption Citrix use to generate the secret. Is there a way to get plain secret out of it.

I have tried to validate online TOTP tool secret and it works in Azure AD B2C also tried token based code that also works in Azure AD B2C. The Citrix TOTP secret does not seems to be working.